# What is wrong with ReactCSSTransitionGroup?

Tags: css, animation, reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

I have this code inside `render()` function in my component:

```
..
<ReactCSSTransitionGroup
  transitionName="testing"
  transitionEnterTimeout={600}
  transitionLeaveTimeout={600}>

  <div>testing animations!</div>

</ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
..
```

And i have this code in my CSS file:

```
.testing-enter {
    animation: slideIn 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
}
.testing-leave {
    animation: slideOut 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
}

@keyframes slideIn {
    0% {
        opacity 0
        transform translate3d(-50px, 0, 0)
    }
    100% {
        opacity 1
        transform translate3d(0, 0, 0)
    }
}
@keyframes slideOut {
    0% {
        opacity: 1
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0
        transform: translate3d(50px, 0, 0)
    }
}
```

I just want my `div` block to slideIn from the right, but nothing happens! Could not find the wrong piece of code, it looks like everything is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have static content inside the `<ReactCSSTransitionGroup/>` tag. You need to have dynamic content. Let's say you need to render `<div>testing animations!</div>` upon mouse click. You need to assign the children to a variable and modify the variable upon mouse click.

```
let myDiv = buttonClicked ? <div>testing animations!</div> : <div></div>

<ReactCSSTransitionGroup
  transitionName="testing"
  transitionEnterTimeout={600}
  transitionLeaveTimeout={600}>

  {myDiv}

</ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
```

If no actions are performed and you simply need to animate it on initial mount, use transition-appear instead.

> ReactCSSTransitionGroup provides the optional prop transitionAppear,
>   to add an extra transition phase at the initial mount of the
>   component. There is generally no transition phase at the initial mount
>   as the default value of transitionAppear is false. The following is an
>   example which passes the prop transitionAppear with the value true.

```
<ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example" transitionAppear={true} transitionAppearTimeout={500}>
   <div>testing animations!</div>
</ReactCSSTransitionGroup>


.example-appear {
  opacity: 0.01;
}

.example-appear.example-appear-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}
```